# MSChart inside a usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Can you use the new Microsoft Chart Control for .NET Framework inside a usercontrol? Bacause when i take a working chart from my page and then copy it to a usercontrol the picture is blank very weird. Is there something wrong in my chart settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I am currently using the MS Chart Control within user controls (.ascx) in my application.

I suspect you will need to debug your page + control to see exactly why it is not working as expected.

But i would assure you that there are no inherent issues with having a chart control within a user control.